# Evaluation order of Java operators && vs ||

Tags: java, logical-operators

I have this simple code block

```
int a = 10;
int b = 20;
int c = 30;
boolean result = a++ == 10 || b++ == 20 && c++ < 30;
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(b);
System.out.println(c);
System.out.println(result);
```

When I run this, the console is

```
11
20
30
true
```

This result tell me that only `a++ == 10` is evaluated.

As I read from this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html,
operator `&&` have higher priority than `||` and should be evaluated first. In this book OCA Java SE 8 Programmer I Certification Guide, at twist 2.4, a similar example give the answer that all the logical operands will be evaluated. `&&` is evaluated first and `||` is the last.

But the result give me an assumption that the priority is just used to group operands and operators.
From this `a++ == 10 || b++ == 20 && c++ < 30` to this  `a++ == 10 || (b++ == 20 && c++ < 30)` When expression is evaluated, it is short-circuited by the value `true` on the left of `||`. So the expression on the right (the `&&` operator) is not evaluated.
Because if the operator `&&` is evaluated first, the value of `b` and `c` will be increased but it does not.

Am I correct? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [tutorial page on operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) only gives you an informal description of the operator precedence, when the java code is executed. The table shown on the page does not exists as such in the JLS. The execution/evaluation order depends on how the source code is parsed and how the parse tree is generated.

A code fragment as `a || b && c` (in this example code) will be parsed as an [`Expression`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-Expression):

> ```
> Expression:
>   LambdaExpression
>   AssignmentExpression
> ```

In this case, it's an [`AssignmentExpression`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-AssignmentExpression):

> ```
> AssignmentExpression:
>   ConditionalExpression
>   Assignment
> ```

In this case, it's a [`ConditionalExpression`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-ConditionalExpression):

> ```
> ConditionalExpression:
>   ConditionalOrExpression
>   ConditionalOrExpression ? Expression : ConditionalExpression
>   ConditionalOrExpression ? Expression : LambdaExpression
> ```

In this case, it's a [`ConditionalOrExpression`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-ConditionalOrExpression) (the first line, not the one with the tenary operator):

> ```
> ConditionalOrExpression:
>   ConditionalAndExpression
>   ConditionalOrExpression || ConditionalAndExpression
> ```

And here we will have it translated to the second line (`ConditionalOrExpression || ConditionalAndExpression`) as we have the `"||"` characters here (the actual [`||` operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.24)).

The JLS specifies that the left operand of the `||` operator is evaluated first by [15.7.1. Evaluate Left-Hand Operand First](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7.1):

> The left-hand operand of a binary operator appears to be fully evaluated before any part of the right-hand operand is evaluated.

It also specifies, that the `||` operator is "short-circuited", as defined in [15.24. Conditional-Or Operator ||](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.24):

> The conditional-or operator `||` operator is like `|` (§15.22.2), but evaluates its right-hand operand only if the value of its left-hand operand is `false`.

In total this means that the left operand is evaluated (`a++ == 10`, which will increase the variable `a`) and because this comparison results in `true`, the right operand will NOT be evaluated. So neither `b++` nor `c++` will be evaluated in any way.

Comment: Thank you for the effort. With that parse tree,I think i got it now.

Answer (score 1):

The evaluation order without parenthesis is from left to right.
Since the first evaluation was true and because the operant is || the rest is not executing. (The same will happened if your first result was false and then you have an && operant).

The ++ operator executes always after the comparison execution.
(In C++ there are two different operators  ++c and c++ then you can choose when the addition takes place)

Nice thoughts!!!

Answer (score 0):

> This result tell me that only a++ == 10 is evaluated.

Which is the result that the language definition dictates.

> But the result give me an assumption that the priority is just used to
> group operands and operators.

You are correct.